# Click on a table row data should redirect to a html page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

In my html page, i have a table with few rows.If i click on a row, i need to redirect the page to another html page.How to perform this by using jquery.

Note:I need to redirect each row of data to distinct html pages.For example first row data should redirect to user1 profile html page.second row of data should redirect to user2 profile html page.

```
<table class="table">

    <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>user 1</td>
            <td>10/21/2013</td>
            <td class="text-primary">Open</td>
            <td>$79.99</td>
            <td>Amazing Widget (16 GB, White)</td>
            <td>Johnathan</td>
            <td class="text-right none"> <a href="#" class="tick_icon gridneed_icon"></a>
 <a class="col-md-offset-1 cross_icon gridneed_icon" data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteproduct"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user 2</td>
            <td>6/21/2013</td>
            <td class="text-primary">Open</td>
            <td>$79.99</td>
            <td>Amazing (16 GB, White)</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td class="text-right none"> <a href="#" class="tick_icon gridneed_icon"></a>
 <a class="col-md-offset-1 cross_icon gridneed_icon" data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteproduct"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try something like this, use data attribute like below one

**HTML CODE**

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-url="some_url1">
            <td>39401602</td>
            <td>6/21/2013</td>
            <td class="text-primary">Open</td>
            <td>$79.99</td>
            <td>Amazing Widget (16 GB, White)</td>
            <td>Johnathan Doe</td>
            <td class="text-right none"> <a href="#" class="tick_icon gridneed_icon"></a>
    <a class="col-md-offset-1 cross_icon gridneed_icon" data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteproduct"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-url="some_url2">
            <td>39401602</td>
            <td>6/21/2013</td>
            <td class="text-primary">Open</td>
            <td>$79.99</td>
            <td>Amazing Widget (16 GB, White)</td>
            <td>Johnathan Doe</td>
            <td class="text-right none"> <a href="#" class="tick_icon gridneed_icon"></a>
    <a class="col-md-offset-1 cross_icon gridneed_icon" data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteproduct"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
$(function () {
    $('table.table tr').click(function () {
        window.location.href = $(this).data('url');
    });
})
```

**REFERENCE**

Data Attribute - http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**window.location.href**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

```
$('table tr').on('click', 'td', function () {
   window.location.href = "redirect url";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
                <tr data-link="url1"> ... </tr>
                <tr data-link="url2"> ... </tr>
        <tbody>
</table>
```

**js** [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$('table.table tr').click(function(){
   window.location.href = $(this).data('link');
});
```

Read [5 ways to redirect URL with Javascript](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html)

Comment: I need to redirect each row of data to distinct pages

Comment: Yes its working fine.Thank You.If i need to open the page in a new tab means what i have to use like target=blank for <a> tag..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

jquery:

```
                $("tr").click(function(){

                        window.location.href=$(this).attr('link');
                });
```

HTML:

```
            <table class="table">

                <tbody>
                        <tr  link="http://google.com">
                        <td>user 1</td>
                        <td>6/21/2013</td>
                        <td class="text-primary">Open</td>
                        <td>$79.99</td>
                        <td>Amazing Widget (16 GB, White)</td>
                        <td>Johnathan Doe</td>
                        <td class="text-right none"> <a href="#" class="tick_icon gridneed_icon"></a>
             <a class="col-md-offset-1 cross_icon gridneed_icon" data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteproduct"></a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr link="http://stackoverflow.com">
                        <td>user 2</td>
                        <td>6/21/2013</td>
                        <td class="text-primary">Open</td>
                        <td>$79.99</td>
                        <td>Amazing Widget (16 GB, White)</td>
                        <td>Johnathan Doe</td>
                        <td class="text-right none"> <a href="#" class="tick_icon gridneed_icon"></a>
             <a class="col-md-offset-1 cross_icon gridneed_icon" data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteproduct"></a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Open in new window,

```
                $("tr").click(function(){
                        //window.location.href=$(this).attr('link');
                        var url = $(this).attr('link');
                        window.open(url,'_blank');
                });
```

Comment: Can you suggest some solution to open the redirection page in a new tab- like we are using <a href="http://google.com/" target=_blank">